# JS regex match, condition without capturing

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture number after 'id-odes=' but only number without this phrase. I wrote something like this

```
"id-odes=50388635:id-odes=503813535:id-odes=50334635"
    .match(/(?:id-odes=)([0-9]*)/g);
```

but it returns

```
["id-odes=50388635", "id-odes=503813535", "id-odes=50334635"]
```

instead of

```
[50388635, 503813535, 50334635]
```

Please help and explain why my way doesn't work properly.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to create a group out of "id-odes=" at all, can't you just skip the first pair of parentheses?

Comment: @RipperDoc I need only ids returned but ids after 'id-odes=' in string

Answer (score 4):

Instead of just outputting the array, you can iterate over the results:

```
var re =/id-odes=([0-9]*)/g,
s = "id-odes=50388635:id-odes=503813535:id-odes=50334635";

while ((match = re.exec(s)) !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oqerul/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the matches then you can use something like:

```
s = "id-odes=50388635:id-odes=503813535:id-odes=50334635"  
re = /(?:id-odes=)([0-9]*)/
while (match = re.exec(s))
{
    console.log(match[1]); // This is the number part
}
```

Assuming the whole string is in exactly this format you can of course use
`"id-odes=50388635:id-odes=503813535:id-odes=50334635".match(/[0-9]+/g)` but that of course breaks if there are any other numbers in the string.

Explanation why `.match(/(?:id-odes=)([0-9]*)/g);` gives you the wrong result is quite simple: You get back everything that the regex matched, regardless of capturing groups.

Comment: It works but it's not what I looking for, I want to get results in matches array without iterating if it's possible

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible, albeit a very very fragile solution. It will work if you really and exacly know that all the data coming in are in this exact format (i.e. you want to extract all numbers)